# Exclusive serial port access on OSX

Tags: java, macos, serial-port

I'm working on [an open source program](http://replicat.org/) that uses `gnu.io` ([RXTX](http://users.frii.com/jarvi/rxtx/index.html)) to talk to a microcontroller over a USB serial port.  The app runs on Windows, Linux and OSX.  It relies on `gnu.io` for portable serial port access.  One Macbook user has posted a log showing evidence of two things:

- While the application has the serial port open something causes RTS to pulse, resetting the microcontroller.
- While the application has the serial port open something changes the baudrate temporarily, causing garbage to appear on the input.  (Normally this microcontroller/firmware/USB combination is not susceptible to "line noise" style garbage characteristic of bad baud rates).
- This happens periodically while the application sits idle (reacting/logging when spontaneous messages arrive after the RTS induced reset)

I suspect that some other program is opening the same serial port occasionally (eg searching for a connected device).  How do I prevent that on OSX?

Comment: This sounds like a flaw in RXTX.  It might not be opening the port in exclusive mode and so other applications can open it up.  

Could it be flaky hardware?  The UART chip goes wonky and so the system resets it.

Comment: @MarkRobinson: The UART in my case was an FTDI USB-Serial device.

Comment: As an experiment.  What happens when you try open one serial port from two RXTX applications at the same time?  In particular, on MacOS X.

Comment: @MarkRobinson: I don't have the hardware to test the OSX version.  The details in the question are from experiments I requested of the person reporting the bug.

Comment: You could try SerialIO to find out if it's a RXTX bug or a issue with the hardware/driver.

Comment: you might want to try [JSSC](https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/), it is more stable than RXTX.

Answer (score 2):

as far as I know, RXTX does not allow anyone else to use a Serial port it's using, and throws an exception if the port is already in use when it tries to open it.  sounds like a RXTX bug to me